# Formatting Rich Text Box / Text File in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, formatting

I am currently using `string.Format` to evenly space out lines in a windows form of my application. I have noticed that I when I do so the text lines on my RichTextBox output window are still not aligned. However, when I save them to a text file everything is lined up as I had intended?

Is there a way to make sure that both the RichTextBox and output file (txt file) are BOTH lined up?

Comment: What does that mean:
_However, when I save them to a text file everything is lined up as I had intended?_
When does it look right? When you import it to your RTF control or when you look at it with an external application..?

Comment: When I look at the txt file in "Notepad" it is lined-up as I had intended. When I look at the text output within the RichTextBox it is mis-aligned.

Comment: What font are you using? Notepad will show a space with the same width as a 'W'; The RTB will do that only, if you choose a non-proportional font like Courier or Cosolas.

Comment: That may answer the question ... In Notepad the font is Lucida Consolas ... in my winform RTB it was Microsoft Sans Serif

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your RichTextBox using a font with differing character widths? That would stop spaced items from lining up properly.

Comment: I am using Microsoft Sans Serif ... Is there a preferred font without noticable character width changes that you would recommend?

Comment: Consolas or Courier are quite common monospaced fonts

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use the space-formatted alignment you should use Consolas as the Font to display it. On my machine (win 8.1) this is what Notepad uses by default. It looks pretty good, clearly better than the old typewriter fonts Courier and Courier New.